# Binding on an html element in angular from a string generated html

Tags: html, json, angular

I get given a JSON file and within that there is a property called `html` and this property looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "question": "Who is reporting the claim?",
        "html": "<input type='text' [value]='text'>"
    }
]
```

I get the JSON and in the component I have a variable called `html` which is like below:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  html: string;
  text: string;
}
```

On the `ngInit` function, I get the JSON and set the `html` variable to the HTML in the file.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._appService.getQuestions().subscribe(response => {
      this.html = response[0].html;
    });  
  }
```

This then binds to the view like so:

```
<div class="row" [innerHTML]='html | safeHtml'></div>
```

Now my question is the Input that was generated through the JSON file, how do I bind the value of that to text? As the current implementation does not work.

Comment: why not use *ngif rather than dynamically setting html content?

Comment: @Timothy Sorry. Do you have an example of this for me to look at. There could be a number of questions and answers that are different in design.

Comment: Angular-specific markup is not processed for dynamically added content. Angular compiles a template only when you build your application. There is a way to compile a component at runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ahh, So my string cannot contain a bound property?

Comment: No, at least Angular won't do anything with it.